# How to store empty/null manager field of a user in LDAP?

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

```
@Attribute(name = "manager")
private String manager;

ldapTemplate.create(user);
```

The following code works when I have manager if I format the string like:

"manager": "CN=123456,OU=xxxx,OU=Users,OU=xxxx,OU=xxxx,OU=xxxx,OU=ASP,DC=xxx,DC=local"

But how do a store a user without a manager? Null or empty manager String does not work.

I am using javas spring-ldap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null seems to be what is correct for empty fields in ldap